# How to update a related entity's column on persist/delete/update with Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following entities:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $category;
}
```

And:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     */
    protected $products;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $productCount = 0;

    public function updateProductCount()
    {
        $this->productCount = $this->products->count();
    }
}
```

I would like the `productCount` field of category to be updated whenever its related products are updated/added/removed.  I have created the method `Category::updateProductCount()` to do this but am unsure the best approach.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the role of PHP to do that, you should use sql [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html). And I think you shouldn't have count property in your database. For example you can do :

- select count(*) from product where category = ...
- create an SQL view

Comment: Thanks, I used sql triggers to accomplish this.  I understand I really shouldn't have a count column this solution plays nice with my ORM and keeps it simple.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is what you looking for: [Doctrine2 LifeCycle Events](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events)
Instead of `$this->productCount = $this->products->count();` try `$this->productCount = count($this->products);`

I don't know why you have to store it in the DB. I would just use a getter for it:

```
public function getProductCount(){ return count($this->products); }
```

Comment: The reason for storing in the DB is basically for performance - listing 100 categories with their product count would create 100 COUNT queries.  I know I can use a "virtual" count column, but that makes hydration an issue.